# Descending order of VendorOption:sortBy?

Tags: geoserver, sld

Is there a descending order of `VendorOption:SortBy`?

What is z-ordering?

> It is a common need to perform road casing against a complex road network, which can have its own z-ordering needs (e.g., over and under passes).

For example: `<VendorOption name="sortBy">rank</VendorOption>`

the will be drawn as `1,2,3,4,5`

I want is it has to be drawn as `5,4,3,2,1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage of sortBy is documented in http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/z-order/syntax.html

> The z-ordering is implemented as a new FeatureTypeStyle vendor option,
> sortBy, which controls in which order the features are extracted from
> the data source, and thus painted. The sortBy syntax is the same as
> the WFS one, that is, a list of comma separated field names, with an
> optional direction modifier (ascending being the default):
>
> field1 [A|D], field2 [A|D], ... , fieldN [A|D]
>
> Some examples:
>
> “z”: sorts the features based on the z field, ascending (lower z values are painted first, higher later)
>
> “cat,z D”: sorts the features on the cat attribute, with ascending order, and for those that have the same cat value, the
> sorting is on descending z
>
> “cat D,z D”: sorts the features on the cat attribute, with descending order, and for those that have the same cat value, the
> sorting is on descending z

In your case, use

```
<VendorOption name="sortBy">rank D</VendorOption>
```

Comment: Thank you so much mister! It is quite complicated than I thought. But what is the use of `sortByGroup`?

Comment: They have tried to document that as well, but the meaning is for example to allow to render first all background layers ordered by z-order, and then all the roads on top of background, also ordered by z-order. It makes even the lowest priority road to appear above highest priority background.